# Random timed output circuit

Tags: led, 555, output, time, random

I am in need of some help with a project. I am trying to build a circuit that will turn on three LEDs randomly on a 1-5second cycle.  I have the basic when it comes to electronics, but get stuck on the random part.  I have started with a 555.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas so far.  I'm not very well versed in programming so I am trying to stay away from micro processors.  I have had luck with the 555 and resistors to change the cycle times, it's the random that is throwing me off.  I have considered using a 7041, to try to accomplish this but I just can't seem to get it to work.  As in two lights come on at the same time.

Comment: Sorry a 4017 chip.

Answer (score 1):

If you generate a high(ish) frequency square wave (1kHz or above) with a 555 and feed it into a counter circuit, you can use another 555 set to a frequency like 0.5Hz to latch the outputs of timer every 2 seconds.

You'll need two 555s, a free-running counter and a latch circuit.

The chances are the three outputs you will get will be pretty random.

Here's the counter: -

[image]

And feed three of its outputs into the latch: -

[image]

The three outputs (aligning with the three inputs from the counter) can be used to drive a few mA into 3 LEDs.

Answer (score 1):

This is best done with a microcontroller running a pseudo-random number generator.  Those are easy to code and it doesn't take a lot of bits to create a pattern that look random to a human observer.

Even the PIC 10F200 can do this easily.  All you need is the micro, which comes in a SOT-23 package, and the bypass cap.  One of its outut pins can drive the LED directly.